# How to copy text from different span in one row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code:

```html
<div class="text">
   <span class="word">
      Hello
   <span/>
   <span class="word">
      world!
   <span/>
<div/>
```

I want to copy this text into line `"Hello world!"`

But when I copy it, it looks like:

```
Hello
world!
```

Comment: HTML closing tags use the format `</ name>`, you have `<name />` which is a self-closing tag, and may be producing some odd results.

Comment: Hi there. What's your code please? try to give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so helping you will be easier and faster.

Comment: Hi. Please specifiy what do you mean by "I copy it". How are you copying it? And where are you pasting it?

Answer (score 3):

After fixing your end tags, you likely did the first, but need to use the second method

```js
let text = document.querySelector(".text").textContent;
console.log(text); // does not do what you want

text = [...document.querySelectorAll(".text .word")]
  .map(elem => elem.textContent.trim()) // trim each element's text
  .join(" "); // join with a space
console.log(text); // works better
```

```html
<div class="text">
   <span class="word">
      Hello
   </span>
   <span class="word">
      world!
   </span>
</div>
```

jQuery if you want it

```js
let text = $(".word").text().trim(); // does not work
console.log(text); 

text = $(".word")
  .map(function() { return $(this).text().trim() })
  .get()
  .join(" "); // works better but is not more elegant than the plain JS one
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
   <span class="word">
      Hello
   </span>
   <span class="word">
      world!
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler approach

```js
var words = $('.text .word').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
}).get();

var output = words.join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <span class="word">
      Hello
   </span>
  <span class="word">
      world!
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Still does not work as OP wants it. See [my second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234755/295783)

Comment: Yea, I get it now. Updated my code and I feel it's almost similar to yours. Thanks for correcting me @mplungjan. Do you want me delete the answer?

Comment: That is up to you if you want to delete your identical answer :) I am fine